# How to include edittext in appwidget like Google search widget

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget

I was trying to include an editText in appwidget..later I came to know that it is not possible to include edittext

But if I check Google search appwiget I can see they are using a view similar to edittext.. 
How can I create a view like edittext for widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used TextView instead of EditText  with custom background.. and onClick it will take to the desired screen ..
This looks similar to Twitter and Facebook search widget :)

Comment: I will be able to open a soft keyboard when clicking on the text view, but how can I capture the keyboard inputs and change the text view text accordingly ?

Answer (score 4):

Dianne Hackborn explains on this thread:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a50a2aff0c8c754d/

that the Google search widget is a "special case", built right into the home screen (not a true widget), so they are obviously able to take some liberties.  Pretty sure you're not going to be able to do this, at least not pre-3.0.

Comment: Twitter and Facebook have the EditText like view on their widgets .. Actually they are using TextView for that

Comment: does EditText for widget still cannot be implemented in lollipop and marshmallow?